# Searching through a CSV with variable number of columns

Tags: ruby, csv, file-io

I could use some help thinking about a puzzle I'm solving. I was going to tackle it in Ruby, but could be in another language like Javascript/Node. I'm needing help breaking out the problem and designing.

I'm currently working on a command-line program that reads that reads in a CSV, searches the CSV based on the arguments, and then produces output based on what it finds.

The CSV rows have one of two formats. One is simple is a list of restaurants, food items, and their prices:

```
restaurant ID, price, item label
```

But for restaurants offering combo meals, where there can be any number of
items in a value meal:

```
restaurant ID, price, item 1 label, item 2 label, ...
```

So the idea is that you could run this program with the arguments of the CSV file to read and the food items you want to eat, and it outputs the restaurant they should go to, and the total price it will cost them.  It is okay to purchase extra items, as long as the total cost is minimized.

Sample data.csv

```
1, 4.00, burger 
1, 8.00, tofu_log 
2, 5.00, burger 
2, 6.50, tofu_log

$ foodfinder.rb data.csv burger tofu_log 
=> 2, 11.5
```

Likewise with the rows that have multiple food items:

```
5, 4.00, extreme_fajita
5, 8.00, fancy_european_water
6, 5.00, fancy_european_water
6, 6.00, extreme_fajita, jalapeno_poppers, extra_salsa

$ foodfinder.rb data.csv fancy_european_water extreme_fajita
=> 6, 11.0
```

Since data normalization isn't an option—I can't shove these into a DB—I was wondering how I might go about thinking about how to parse the CSV in an efficient way. Also that some rows have multiple food items has me unsure how to store those. I'm guessing I'd want to import the rows into a hash and then search through the hash in some fashion. Any guidance, wizards?

Comment: If CSV had a standard, that file is not adhering to it.

Comment: @RyPeck: There are various CSV standards but no one pays attention to them :)

Comment: Agree that the CSV format is terrible! Though part of the challenge is to sanitize the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That data is easy to parse with the standard [CSV library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) and a tiny bit of array wrangling:

```
data = CSV.open('data.csv')
          .map { |r| [ r[0], r[1], r[2..-1].map(&:strip) ] }
```

That gives you this in `data`:

```
data = [
    ['5', '4.00', ['extreme_fajita']],
    ['5', '8.00', ['fancy_european_water']],
    #...
]
```

From there it is easy to build whatever indexed structure you need.

However, if you're just interested in finding rows with `'extra_salsa'` then use `select` instead of `map`:

```
want = CSV.open('x.csv')
          .select { |r| r[2..-1].map(&:strip).include?('extra_salsa') }
```

and clean up `want` for printing however you need to.

You're going to be spinning through the whole CSV every time your script runs so you should search it while you're scanning it, building intermediate indexed data structures is just a waste of time if you're only doing one search per run.

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby, I'd skip the standard CSV libraries, and just load the rows, split them into, at most, three pieces, and convert the third into an array. From that point you have all you need:

```
records = file.map { |row|
  row.split(/,\s?/, 3)
}.map { |arr|
  [arr[0].to_i, arr[1].to_f, arr[2].split(/,\s?/)]
}
```

Now your records will be:

```
[
  [5, 4.00, ["extreme_fajita"]],
  [5, 8.00, ["fancy_european_water"]],
  [6, 5.00, ["fancy_european_water"]],
  [6, 6.00, ["extreme_fajita", "jalapeno_poppers", "extra_salsa"]]
]
```

You can use your knowledge on resolving NP-complete problems on this data, that has already the needed form.

Comment: I would consider even not parsing the CSV data at all to begin with. Just grep for rows with the needed strings, and THEN parse it using your way for example. Will be even faster.

Comment: This parsing step is really quick, `grep` won't be much a gain. The really hard problem is to find the optimal cover, as you will discover as soon as you analyze the problem deeply enough.

Comment: So for each restaurnat you have to find (if any) the combination of offers with the minimum price, whose union at the same covers your needs. That's the NP-complete problem. Optimal cover of an arbitrary subset.